Are there Sequential Equilibria that are not Trembling Hand Perfect Equilibria, that don't involve Weakly Dominated strategies?
I'm taking an advanced course (graduate level) in Game Theory. My class has covered several equilibrium concepts, up to Sequential Equilibrium.
The professor said that there are already more refinements out there, but we won't study them in the course. I got curious and started googling about them.
I found about "Trembling Hand Perfect Equilibrium" and was looking for examples: I read the paper " 'Guaranteed lowest prices: do they facilitate collusion?': Revisited " by Kim and Kwon (2018), I also read the example given in Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trembling_hand_perfect_equilibrium) and a couple of examples on YouTube, and what they all have in common is that the Equilibria with weakly dominated strategies get filtered out.
The course professor showed us an "uncredible Sequential Equilibrium" (without defining Trembling Hand Perfection) in an extensive form game, which involved a weakly dominated strategy as well.
Can anyone give me an example that doesn't involve weakly dominated strategies (preferably in extensive form)? Or is the set of Trembling Hand Perfect Equilibria equivalent to the set of undominated Sequential Equilibria?
I haven't found proof of that claim, but haven't found an example that shows otherwise.
I also find it a bit odd that Trembling Hand Perfect Equilibrium makes no mention of "beliefs" even though it is a subset of Sequential Equilibrium, which is based on "beliefs".
